# Azure Data Factory Expression Data Type Conversion Error

Tags: azure-data-factory

This simple expression evaluates correctly at design time when attempting to set a variable value to the following expression:

```
@string(sub(int(variables('TargetRecordCount')), int(variables('SourceTotalRecordCount'))))
```

However when the pipeline is run, the following error occurs:

```
The function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type
```

I have verified that the issue is with the variable '*SourceTotalRecordCount*'. The other variable is sourced from SQL table. The offending variable is obtained from the Lookup activity which references a CSV file.

The output of the Lookup activity is:

[image]

Setting the variable:

```
@activity('Lookup Source Total Record Count').output.value[0].SourceTotalRecordCount
```

The input of the SetVariable activity to define the variable *TotalRecordDifference**emphasized text* is:

[image]

I have used output.FirstRow.SourceTotalRecordCount but it still led to the same error.

Comment: Hi, Expression seems to be fine. Couple of questions, .1 Did you publish the changes before debugging ? 2. did you check the value being assigned to SourceTotalRecordCount during run time from the output tab?

Comment: Hi @AllAboutBI
I have seen some of your BI videos on YouTube. Thanks for stopping by.
Back to your questions: I haven't published the changes because I'm not working off the main branch. I have checked and can confirm the value of SourceTotalRecordCount is properly assigned to the variable. However when the variable is used in the SUB math expression it throws the error I mentioned in the the post.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. As per the error I think the problem is on int and not on sub function. One more thing, Issue could be on the TargetRecordCount variable value too. Try to isolate the issue by just having one expression at a time like string(int(SourceTotalRecordCount)) once and string(int(TargetRecordCount)) next time. Later you can apply sub function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression looks correct. I reproed your expression and was able to get the output without errors.

[image]

[image]

The issue might be with your incoming data. As per the error message, the variable value is invalid for int conversion.

You can debug by testing individual output values by converting them to int in your set variable. While storing the lookup output value into a variable, try to convert it to int there itself to identify the error.

**Example:**

`@string(int(activity('SourceTotalRecordCount').output.value[0].SourceTotalRecordCount))`

[image]

`@string(int(activity('TargetRecordCount').output.value[0].TargetRecordCount))`

[image]

Comment: Ended up being a silly mistake of setting a value to the incorrect variable. All fixed. Thank you all.